# Fearing beyond parents

Tags: halacha-theory, mitzvah

The commandment of respecting parents (kabed et avicha v'et imecha) has "extra" words (et and v'et) which are used in the gemara to include others in the halacha of respect (for a discussion of options, see [here](https://www.dafyomi.co.il/eruvin/halachah/ev-hl-070.htm)).

The commandment to fear the parents (ish imo v'aviv tira'u) has no additional "et" words. Does that mean that the halacha to fear is limited only to the simple biological parent-pair or is there another mechanism which brings in other people and groups under he umbrella of the mitzva?

Comment: I think it is only for the biological parent-pair.